# DocuSign: Required checkbox

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope in docusign with the checkbox will be mandatory. I tried to apply it by using a Tab Groups tab. Below is my request. I'm able to create a document but the checkboxes are still optional. I'm not sure what's wrong in may request: Please check. Thank you.

```
{
    "documents":[
            {
                "documentBase64":"<pdffile>",
                "documentId":"1",
                "fileExtension":"pdf",
                "name":"Document_Name"
            }
        ],
    "emailSubject":"Some Email Subject",
    "recipients":{
        "signers":[
            {
                "email":"some.user@gmail.com",
                "name":"Some People",
                "recipientId":"4250",
                "routingOrder":"1",
                "tabs":{
                    "signHereTabs":[
                        {
                            "anchorString":"PLEASE SIGN HERE",
                            "anchorXOffset":"0",
                            "anchorYOffset":"1.5",
                            "anchorUnits":"cms"
                        }
                    ],
                    "checkboxTabs":[
                        {
                            "tabLabel":"checkbox1",
                            "selected":"false",
                            "required":"false",
                            "documentId":"1",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "anchorString":"[x]",
                            "anchorXOffset":"0",
                            "anchorYOffset":"0",
                            "anchorUnits":"cms",
                            "tabGroupLabels":["Checkbox Group"]
                        },
                        {
                            "tabLabel":"checkbox2",
                            "selected":"false",
                            "required":"false",
                            "documentId":"1",
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "anchorString":"[x]",
                            "anchorXOffset":"0",
                            "anchorYOffset":"1",
                            "anchorUnits":"cms",
                            "tabGroupLabels":["Checkbox Group"]
                        }
                    ],
                    "tabGroups":[
                        {
                            "recipientId":"1",
                            "tabLabel":"Check Boxes",
                            "groupLabel":"Checkbox Group",
                            "groupRule":"SelectAtMost",
                            "maximumAllowed" :"1",
                            "minimumRequired":"0",
                            "validationMessage":"Please check a box",
                            "tabScope":"Document",
                            "locked":"false"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status":"sent"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried this in my request and still, the checkbox remained optional.

```
"tabs":{
    "signHereTabs":[
        {
            "anchorString":"PLEASE SIGN HERE",
            "anchorXOffset":"0",
            "anchorYOffset":"1.5",
            "anchorUnits":"cms"
        }
    ],
    "checkboxTabs":[
        {
            "anchorString":"[x]",
            "anchorXOffset":"0",
            "anchorYOffset":"0",
            "anchorUnits":"cms",
            "tabGroupLabels":[
                "Checkbox Group"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tabGroups":[
        {
            "groupLabel":"Checkbox Group",
            "groupRule":"SelectAtLeast",
            "maximumAllowed":"1",
            "minimumRequired":"1",
            "validationMessage":"Please check a box",
            "tabScope":"document"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using version 2.1, /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions! THANK YOU!

Comment: Please first try using the **exact** same request that I suggest. You left out the `pageNumber` and `documentId` attributes from the `tabGroups` array....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `required` attribute for a checkbox does not apply. Instead create a `tabGroup` for the checkbox or checkboxes. That way you can require that the checkbox be checked, or require that one of the multiple checkboxes be checked, etc.

### Example: one required checkbox

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign the attached document",
    "status": "sent",
    "documents": [
      {
        "documentBase64":"<pdffile>",
        "name": "Example document",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "1"
      }
    ],
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
        {
          "email": "signer_email@example.com",
          "name": "Signer's name",
          "recipientId": "1",
          "clientUserId": "1000",
          "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "anchorXOffset": "20",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
              }
            ],
            "checkboxTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "anchorXOffset": "180",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabGroupLabels": [
                  "checkbox group"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "tabGroups": [
              {
                "groupLabel": "checkbox group",
                "groupRule": "SelectAtLeast",
                "minimumRequired": "1",
                "maximumAllowed": "1",
                "validationMessage": "Please check to indicate your agreement",
                "tabScope": "document",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "documentId": "1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Larry. I used this in my request, but the checkbox still Optional. Can you help me to figure out what's wrong or missing in my request? Thank you. 
 
 
 "checkboxTabs":[
  {
   "anchorString":"[x]",
   "anchorXOffset":"0",
   "anchorYOffset":"0",
   "anchorUnits":"cms",
   "tabGroupLabels":[
    "Checkbox Group"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "tabGroups":[
  {
   "groupLabel":"Checkbox Group",
   "groupRule":"SelectAtLeast",
   "maximumAllowed":"1",
   "minimumRequired":"1",
   "validationMessage":"Please check a box",
   "tabScope":"document"
  }
 ]

Comment: Please update (edit) your question to include your added question. Also, make sure that you are using API version 2.1.

Comment: Hi LarryK, you're correct. I worked After I added the pageNumber, documentId in my request. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a checkbox like a EULA that said something along the lines of 'Check this box to agree to the above', and then a signature.

The requirement was that they should not be able to 'finish' the document unless they've checked the checkbox.

Although the selected answer works, it's complicated and requires you to specify a document_id and a page_number to work. I tried lots of other combinations using tab_scope = 'envelope' but it just ignored the tab group. Furthermore, the labeling and validation messages around the tab_group are confusing to end-users. In the end, I think it's just "the wrong tool for the job"

Instead I used an 'Approved' tab, but gave it a single space for the 'button_text', and then set the height and width.

They will not be able to finish the document unless they click the Approve 'button' which presents as a checkbox to the user when configured in this way.

My envelope definition looked something like this in the end:

```
{
"emailSubject": "Please sign the attached document",
"status": "sent",
"documents": [
  {
    "documentBase64":"<pdffile>",
    "name": "Example document",
    "fileExtension": "pdf",
    "documentId": "1"
  }
],
"recipients": {
  "signers": [
    {
      "email": "signer_email@example.com",
      "name": "Signer's name",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "1000",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [
          {
            "anchorString": "/sig1/",
            "anchorXOffset": "20",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels"
          }
        ],
        "approveTabs": [
          {
            "anchorString": "/app1/",
            "anchorXOffset": "0",
            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
            "buttonText": " ", #if you don't put a space, it defaults back to 'Approve' for button_text
            "width": 18,
            "height": 18
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}